# Como guardar datos de CheckBoxList C# ASP.NET en sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

quiero saber como guardo los valores checkeados del siguiente cbl en mi base de datos sql.
Entiendo que puede hacerse con un condicional pero no encuentro la forma

```
                                        <label class="form-check-label">Dias</label>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align:left">
                                            <label class="container">
                                                Lunes
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbxDays" value="1" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="container">
                                                Martes
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbxDays" value="2" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="container">
                                                Miercoles
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbxDays" value="3" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="container">
                                                Jueves
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbxDays" value="4" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="container">
                                                Viernes
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbxDays" value="5" />
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta, podrias ser un poco mas claro para poder brindarte una mejor ayuda

Comment: ¿De casualidad te da null cuando los recibes en el controlador?

Comment: pues puedes recibir un arreglo de los checkbox en el controlador, algo como  string[] cbxDays   o si son enteros int[] cbxDays;

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Son dias de semana para horarios de clases, lo que quiero hacer es guardar solo los valores que tilda el usuario en la base de datos. Y no se como hacer el procedimiento para comprobar esto

Comment: @fredyfx No me da null porque no he realizado ningun procedimiento. https://github.com/matiastulli/MarvellaUniversidad/blob/master/MarvellaUniversidad/Areas/Management/Pages/Account/RegisterSubjects.cshtml

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 de preferencia mira el video donde está la charla que comparto. Te ayudará mucho